# html form query using check boxes

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am developing a a cancer risk assesment tool in phpmysql. The user will need to select risks and symptoms from a html form containing check boxes and then then the choices will be checked against what is stored in the database. This is the form.
[image: html form to asses cancer risk]

Here are screenshots of data stored in the mysql database which the submitted checkboxes will be checked against.

oesophageal_carcinoma_riskfactors_tbl
[image: riskfactors]

oesophageal_carcinoma_symptoms_tbl
[image: symptoms]

oesophageal_carcinoma_riskfactors_tbl
[image: response: table containing response the user should get after submiting the html form with checkboxes]

In case someone checked the html for as here

[image]

The response to be fetched by the query should be come from responseID = 1 from the response table.

How should my table linking foreign keys look and how should the PHP code to query the database look like.

Comment: I'm not clear on how you determine which response is used?

Comment: This looks like a school assignment.

Comment: i guess we need a relations table linking the riskfactors, symptoms and response tables....any idea how we do it perfectly

Comment: DiMono: I am a medic and am developing a ultra high yield cancer risk and symptoms systems

Answer (score 0):

Nick, you are correct in your comment when you say you need a "relations" table. I suggest creating one table with its own primary key and the 3 additional columns that server as foreign keys. E.g:

```
|id|risk_id|symptom_id|response_id|
___________________________________
| 1|    2  |   3      |     4     |
```

And for good measure index the foreign key columns.

Comment: then how should the php code to query the database look like?

Comment: i am trying to think on the structure of the relation table but it becoming complex....how big will the table to cover someone at risk and someone who probably has the carcinoma?

Comment: your best bet is trial and error. No one here will provide the full answer for you. The project and relational table is more complex than you think. The relational table is a many to many relationship. You can derive to multiple responses based on multiple risk factors and symptoms. so all those combinations need to be accounted for in your relations table.